# How to format and to indent correctly some java code in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, format, indentation

I've got a class with a plenty of methods containing some blank line and bad formatting.

For instance :

```
public Map<String, String> attenteDevisDentaire(Map<String, String> aRetourAnnul, String aCodeGroupe,
        //BLANK LINE HERE 
        ObjectFormBean anObjectFormBean, DossierPecComplet aDossierPecComplet)
//BLANK LINE HERE 
{       //CURLY BRACKETS NOT INLINE WITH THE METHOD'S DEFINITION
    remplieFormulaireAbandonPsEtBeneficiaire(aRetourAnnul, aCodeGroupe, aDossierPecComplet, anObjectFormBean);
    return abandonner(aRetourAnnul, aCodeGroupe, anObjectFormBean, aDossierPecComplet);
}
```

Is there a way to format and to indent absolutely everthing correctly with Eclipse like below ?

```
public Map<String, String> attenteDevisDentaire(Map<String, String> aRetourAnnul, String aCodeGroupe, ObjectFormBean anObjectFormBean, DossierPecComplet aDossierPecComplet){
    remplieFormulaireAbandonPsEtBeneficiaire(aRetourAnnul, aCodeGroupe, aDossierPecComplet, anObjectFormBean);
    return abandonner(aRetourAnnul, aCodeGroupe, anObjectFormBean, aDossierPecComplet);
}
```

I've already formatted everything and indent with the eclipse's tools but it doesnt do the job as i want.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can personalize the formater in the menu Windows/Preferences/Java/Code Style/Formatter, you have a lot of options

Comment: Go into the preferences to Java->Code Style->Formatter and you can edit how eclipse autoformat handles your code and formats it.

Comment: Also, you can enable automatic formatting in the Save Actions (Java - Editor - Sava Actions)

Answer (score 0):

You can normally format & indent code in Eclipse with

Format:

> Control + Shift + F

Imports:

> Control + Shift + O

The way it formats can be Edited here:

> Windows/Preferences/Java/Code Style/Formatter

Comment: is it not Control + Shift + F  ?

Comment: Edited, I was thinking about imports for whatever reason ;)

Comment: Already did that ! I just want to delete absolutely every single blank line and put the definition of the method in inline .....

Comment: Windows/Preferences/Java/Code Style/Formatter

Answer (score 0):

Go to >Window/Preferences/Code Style/Formatter
Then Edit the active profile (or whichever you want to have that effect on), go to Blank Lines and set the properties to achieve the desired effect.